# OData Null Navigation Property while using Typeless Entity Object Support in Web API

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

I have two types Person and Honorific with a 0..1 to Many relationship between them. I am using queryOptions.request.SetSelectExpandClass to support expand and it works perfectly to expand Honorific when there is an Honorific.

When there is no Honorific I need the Json payload to include Honorific=(null). In that situation I return a  null from TryGetPropertyValue but the Json serializer completely omits any reference to Honorific where it should insert Honorif=(null).  Any ideas on how to achieve this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OData allows that the value of a collection is null.
A null collection is handled by WebAPI which will ignore a null collection during serialization.
I think it is a bug in WebAPI and a null collection should be treated as an empty collection during serialization.

Check the source code of WebAPI blow:
For OData V3:
`\src\System.Web.Http.OData\OData\Formatter\Serialization\ODataEntityTypeSerializer.cs:WriteExpandedNavigationProperty`
For OData V4:
`\src\System.Web.OData\OData\Formatter\Serialization\ODataEntityTypeSerializer.cs:WriteExpandedNavigationProperty`